# x64dbg - Conditional breakpoint based on function argument

Tags: windows, x86, x64dbg, breakpoint

How can I set a conditional breakpoint based on the argument of a function?

I am trying to break on the windows function `LoadLibraryExW`: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexw

I want to break on this function only when the first argument (`lpLibFileName`) is equal to `L"Test.dll"`. When I break on the function I can see that `L"Test.dll"` is `esp+4`.

I've tried a few different variations without success. They either break on every `LoadLibraryExW` calls or none. Variations like:

```
Break Condiditon: [esp+4]==L"Test.dll"
Break Condition: esp+4==L"Test.dll"
etc..
```

What is the proper way of setting a conditional breakpoint based on function arguments? Or register offsets?

Comment: In this specific case you can just set a DLL breakpoint for “Test.dll”

Comment: Thanks for that. Will keep this open as I'm still interested in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @mrexodia  you can set a DLL breakpoint

```
Typ Address  Module/La State   Disassembly H Summa
DLL                               
    76850000 gdi32.dll Enabled  0 all()
```

Go to breakpoint window (alt+b) -> Right Click Add Dll BreakPoint

Type test.dll

This will break when test.dll is loaded

String compare as such isn't yet implemented. A bug report exists from 2017 and a workaround exists which states using a third party plugin
which you can check out.

Or simply split the string into bytes and compare  the bytes 
like

```
Type     Address  Module/Label/Exception     State   Disassembly H Summary                                                                                         
Software                                                           
         76ACE8A5 <kernel32.dll.CreateFileW> Enabled mov edi,edi 5 breakif((1:[[esp+4]+0xc] == 66) &&  (1:[[esp+4]+0xe] == 69)), log("brk hit   { 1:[[esp+4]+c] }")
```

[image]

x64dbg has broken when file testmefive.txt was opened for source code below with above byte compare method

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *filenames[] = {
        "testmeone.txt",
        "testmetwo.txt",
        "testmethree.txt",
        "testmefour.txt",
        "testmefive.txt"};
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        FILE *fp = NULL;
        errno_t err = fopen_s(&fp, filenames[i], "r");
        if (err == 0 && fp != 0)
        {
            char buff[0x50] = {0};
            fread_s(buff, 0x50, 1, 0x50, fp);
            printf("%s\n", buff);
            fclose(fp);
        }
    }
}
```