# x64dbg how to set conditional breakpoint on WinAPI function

Tags: x64dbg, breakpoint, winapi

I am trying to solve a GUI based crackme. https://crackmes.one/crackme/5c68758633c5d4776a837cc4 so that I learn security. I want to set a conditional Break point on `user32.CallWindowProcA`. [Microsoft Documents this function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-callwindowproca) as follows

```
LRESULT CallWindowProcA(
  WNDPROC lpPrevWndFunc,
  HWND    hWnd,
  UINT    Msg,
  WPARAM  wParam,
  LPARAM  lParam
);
```

I set the following conditional break points for [WM_LBUTTONDOWN (0x202)](https://wiki.winehq.org/List_Of_Windows_Messages) as follows. But they are not being hit when I click the button :( help

```
Type     Address  Module/Label/ State   Disassembly                            Hits Summary                                              
Software                                                                            
         0041A995 crackme-4.exe Enabled push ebp                               3255 sub_41a995 ?dialogProc?, breakif(arg.get(1) == 0x202)
         0041B9A2 crackme-4.exe Enabled call dword ptr ds:[<&CallWindowProcA>] 1713 breakif((1:[esp+0xc] == 0x202) )
         0041F086 crackme-4.exe Enabled call dword ptr ds:[<&CallWindowProcA>] 0    breakif((1:[esp+0xc] == 0x202))
         0041F11B crackme-4.exe Enabled call dword ptr ds:[<&CallWindowProcA>] 273  breakif((1:[esp+0xc] == 0x202))
         00437E9E crackme-4.exe Enabled mov byte ptr ss:[ebp-4],21             0    
         749055C0 user32.dll    Enabled mov edi,edi                            636  breakif(arg.get(1) == 0x202)
```

I have read through and tried 
[x64dbg - Conditional breakpoint based on function argument](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20411/x64dbg-conditional-breakpoint-based-on-function-argument) but i could not get it to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue some time ago, updating to the latest x64dbg version solved that problem.
You also have to set bps like that:

```
[esp+0xC] == 0x202
```